# Failing to inflate a png inside a plist with Windows using Cocos2D-X

Tags: windows, png, plist, cocos2d-x, inflate

I am running the particleWithFile() function of Coco2D-X, with a plist file created with Mac. The image data is embedded in the plist file, using the "textureImageData" key.
With Mac it works fine, but with Windows it fails, on CCAssert(isOK), see Coco2D-X code below (CCParticleSystem.cpp):

```
char *textureData = (char*)valueForKey("textureImageData", dictionary);
CCAssert(textureData, "");

int dataLen = strlen(textureData);
if(dataLen != 0) 
{
    // if it fails, try to get it from the base64-gzipped data  
    int decodeLen = base64Decode((unsigned char*)textureData, (unsigned int)dataLen,          &buffer);
    CCAssert( buffer != NULL, "CCParticleSystem: error decoding textureImageData");
    CC_BREAK_IF(!buffer);

    int deflatedLen = ZipUtils::ccInflateMemory(buffer, decodeLen, &deflated);
    CCAssert( deflated != NULL, "CCParticleSystem: error ungzipping textureImageData");
    CC_BREAK_IF(!deflated);

    image = new CCImage();
    bool isOK = image->initWithImageData(deflated, deflatedLen);
    CCAssert(isOK, "CCParticleSystem: error init image with Data");
    CC_BREAK_IF(!isOK);
    m_pTexture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addUIImage(image, fullpath.c_str());
}
```

It seems the the decoding passes successfully, and the problem is inside inflate() function of zlib, failing to unzip the png file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're throwing around a bunch of terms that mean different things, so you're code may be similarly confused.  "unzip" is different from "ungzipping" is different from what's in a png file.  You can't "unzip" a png file.  png files contain zlib-wrapped data.  zip, gzip, and zlib are three different formats which are all different wrappers around raw deflate-compressed data.  You need to check what format ccInflateMemory is expecting, and make sure that that's what you're giving it.

Comment: Sorry for not being an expert, I guess that's why I am here asking questions... As I said, it is not my code, but Cocos2d-x code, using zlib. By "unzipping", I meant "ungziping" the png file. I don't think there is anything wrong with the format, as it successfully inflating some other embedded png.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem.

Apparently my resource wasn't a png file but a tiff file. So Inflate() returned a correct buffer (of a tiff file - looked too long for me, so I suspected it was erroneous), but initWithImageData() failed to create an image, since tiff are not supported by Cocos2d-x on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the problem because I set the CC_USE_TIFF to 0.

After I recovery the CC_USE_TIFF to 1,the problem resolved.